# One function in jquery, any step by step guides out there on how to Reset it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".aj-hidden").hide();

jQuery(".aj-hidden").addClass("aj-visible");
jQuery(".aj-collapse").one( 'click', function() {
rel = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
jQuery("#" + rel).slideToggle('fast');
});
});
```

Sorry if this is impossible to do, I have searched all over this site with little idea if I'm even looking at the right answer.

Its taken me some time to figure out the "one" function and it gets me half the way there, I just want to know if I can possibly reset the link to be clicked again afterwards?

Comment: Change `.one()` to `.on()`? I'm not even sure what it is that you're asking.

Comment: are you asking how to remove event handler ?

Comment: the link sends itself off into a loop when clicked, as for some reason ajax is loading the script multiple times, having it set to 'one' works for half the battle but I was just wondering if there was a way to reset the link to be click able again

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a function to be used multiple times why don't you use the [.click() attribute of jQuery?](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

That would look like:

```
jQuery(".aj-collapse").click( function() {
  rel = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
  jQuery("#" + rel).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: because the above jquery in my original post is being called into a page using ajax and starts to loop once the first link is pressed.

Comment: .one( 'click', function()   <- stops the loop from ever starting, but I want the link to be clickable again once its done its thing.

Comment: Then you need to code a jQuery call in the success of the Ajax call.

Comment: I think I've got it using    jQuery(".aj-collapse").off("click").on('click', function()   but apparently I'm not allowed to answer my own question.

Comment: Yes, you just have to wait 8 hours.  So, you just wanted the function just to toggle after the Ajax is done loading?